# We weren't able to connect you to the Windows Store

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-store, microsoft-surface

I know this has been asked at least 100 Times, but still, I can't connect to the Windows Store on my new Surface RT running Windows 8.1 Preview. I tried:

- disable proxy
- correct date and time
- wsreset.exe
- reinsetting the PC (but I got the Surface as developer device one day ago and the problem existed since I booted up the first time)
- Installing  all the Updates (but it always says it wasn't able to complete the configuration of the PC and ins restoring the PC)
- signing in with a local account instand of a MS account

But it all didn't work.

If it helps anybody, here is the winstore log file:

```
 2014-01-18 10:13:03.791, _Info_                WS   [00001044:00002416] CNetworkState: Connected = true, Overage = false, MaxDownloadSize = -1
 2014-01-18 10:13:03.806, _Info_                WS   [00001044:00002416] CUpdateCountPublisher::Initialize: Registered CUpdateCountPublisher
 2014-01-18 10:13:03.806, _Info_                WS   [00001044:00002416] CInstallProgressManager::RefreshUpdatesInstallState: Updates are NOT in Progress
 2014-01-18 10:13:03.900, _Info_                WS   [00001044:00002416] visibilityState changed to: visible
 2014-01-18 10:13:03.900, _Info_                WS   [00001044:00002416] CWinStore::_ClearErrorPage: Navigating home
 2014-01-18 10:13:03.900, _Info_                WS   [00001044:00002416] navigateUI: Navigating 'WS' iframe to  https://wscont.apps.microsoft.com/winstore/A43F8337-2B31-4735-A006-9328167C3098/6.3/754/WW/de-de/0/31/Home.htm
 2014-01-18 10:13:03.916, _Info_                WS   [00001044:00002416] navigateAjax: Loading file:  https://wscont.apps.[I had to remove parts of the link because I hadn't enough Reputation to do this].com/winstore/A43F8337-2B31-4735-A006-9328167C3098/6.3/754/WW/de-de/0/31/Home.htm
 2014-01-18 10:13:03.947, _Info_                WS   [00001044:00002416] navigateAjax: Response received; href =  https://wscont.apps.[I had to remove parts of the link because I hadn't enough Reputation to do this].com/winstore/A43F8337-2B31-4735-A006-9328167C3098/6.3/754/WW/de-de/0/31/Home.htm
 2014-01-18 10:13:03.963, _Info_                WS   [00001044:00002416] WinStore.Navigation received a resume event.
 2014-01-18 10:13:04.010, _Info_                WS   [00001044:00002416] Frame.onResize: CurrentOrientation: landscape
 2014-01-18 10:13:04.025, _Info_                WS   [00001044:00002416] SQR::GetHomePageData: Querying cache.
 2014-01-18 10:13:04.025, _Info_                WS   [00001044:00002416] om.showPicksForYou: queueing overlapped callback
 2014-01-18 10:13:04.072, _Info_                WS   [00001044:00000336] WinStoreCache::DoQuery:  Provider 2 returned 2034 bytes (0x08a409b0) for GetInstalledAppList
 2014-01-18 10:13:04.572, _Error_               WS   [00001044:00001244] DownloadUrl failed - 400 for  [I had to remove parts of the link because I hadn't enough Reputation to do this]browse/6.3.9431-0/754/de-DE_de-DE.de/c/DE/cp/10005001/HomePageData/pt/arm/lf/1/os//
 2014-01-18 10:13:04.572, _Warning_             WS   [00001044:00001244] WinStoreCache::DoQuery: Provider 0 returned failure for HomePageData, hr=0x80190190
 2014-01-18 10:13:04.572, _Error_               WS   [00001044:00002416] CHomePageData::OnEvent: hrEvent=0x80190190, navigating to error page.
 2014-01-18 10:13:04.572, _Error_               WS   [00001044:00002416] CWinStore::_NavigateToErrorPage: Wir konnten keine Verbindung mit dem Store herstellen. Möglicherweise ist ein Serverproblem oder eine Zeitüberschreitung der Netzwerkverbindung aufgetreten. Warten Sie bitte einige Minuten, und <a id='linkRefresh'>versuchen Sie es noch mal</a>.
 2014-01-18 10:13:04.603, _Warning_             WS   [00001044:00002416] onAjaxPageLoaded: Navigating to new page while a page navigation is already in progress
 2014-01-18 10:13:04.603, _Info_                WS   [00001044:00002416] om.invalidateCallbacks: invalidating callbacks
 2014-01-18 10:13:04.666, _Info_                WS   [00001044:00001244] WinStoreCache::DoQuery:  Provider 2 returned 2034 bytes (0x08a409b0) for GetInstalledAppList
 2014-01-18 10:13:07.428, _Info_                WS   [00001044:00002416] visibilityState changed to: Hilden
```

I hope Theres is a Solution for this Problem

Comment: You do understand that the Preview is going expire very shortly right?  You might be better of simply reinstalling Windows RT 8.0 using the factory image and upgrading it to the updated Windows RT 8.1

Comment: Sounds like your best bet would be to call MS's support.

Comment: I had connection issues with the apps, when the DNS Client service was stopped. Make sure this service runs

Comment: @Ramhound It expired 3 days ago. Computers still running the preview will restart every two hours.

Comment: @Ramhound According to Microsoft, once you've updated Windows RT to the preview, unlike Windows 8, you can't revert to Windows RT 8.0.

Comment: I your Surface still in warranty and do you have a Microsoft Store near you?

Comment: It sounds the simple solution would be to use the recovery image supplied by Microsoft.

Comment: I finally got it working: the problem was that Windows wasn't activated and for some reason, that stopped the store from working (Windows is good in displaying error messages that have nothing to do with the error itseft)

Comment: Not sure why my answer was deleted I guess someone way smarter than me decided it wasn't good enough, but anyway, if none of these solutions work for you (the answers in the linked question at the top) try this, cuz after many hours of searching this link is what finally fixed it for me, specifically if you're using the 8.1 beta: http://gshaw0.wordpress.com/2013/08/22/fixing-the-windows-8-1-we-werent-able-to-connect-the-store-error/